# How to increase accuracy in Coreference resolution for a chat conversation?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I need to resolve coreferences but the input text is excerpted from a chat conversation so the accuracy of the tool(*Stanford Corenlp*), currently being used, is low owing to the dialogue between two persons.

Answer (score 0):

This a domain adaptation problem, that your input is in a different domain than pre-trained Corenlp models.

The simplest way to tackle this problem is to normalize your input before using Stanford Corenlp (like using twitter normalizers e.g. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/TweetNLP/). Normalization can help a bit but not solve the problem completely.

If you have more resources and money you can use crowdsourcing for labeling your data and training your own model for this task.